# ttest_ind giving TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, p-value, t-test

I have a dataframe that looks like:

df:

```
  Method    Success
  A         0.67
  B         0.71
  C         0.88
  A         0.91
  B         0.45
  C         0.91
```

Code:

```
 t,p= stats.ttest_ind(group["Method"],group["Success"])
```

Output:

```
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: That isn't how you use `ttest_ind`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to have p-value to get correlation between algorithms, In shor the output should indicate that Method 'A' has impact on success because p-value is <0.05 etc

Comment: What are you comparing? A to the everything else? A to B, A to C, B to C etc?

Comment: A to B, A to C, B to C etc?

Comment: You need to extract those groups and then perform the ttest on the success values.

Comment: Can you suggest an answer

Comment: If you want to make a meaningful statistical comparison between groups, you need more than one observation per group. Currently, you show only one value per group, "Success". What does "Success" represent? What is the data on which "Success" is based? Also, you wrote "correlation" between algorithms. The independent sample t-test is typically used to test a null hypothesis about the means of values in two groups. "Correlation" between groups is something else. Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.